# Add an element on the last Jekyll loop of posts

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I'm sure this is simple but cant find the answer.

There is a standard Jekyll/Liquid post iterator. How do i use the `{% if %}` statement below to put the `<hr>` element for each post **except** the last?

```
<ul class="post-list">
    {% for post in site.posts %}
      {% if post.url %}
      <br>
        <li>
          <h2>
            <a class="post-link" href="{{ post.url | prepend: site.baseurl }}">{{ post.title }}</a>
          </h2>
          <span class="post-meta">{{ post.date | date: "%b %-d, %Y" }}</span>
        </li>

        **** {% if post != $last %} ***** How do i do this??
          <hr>
        {% endif %}
      {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Yep, there's an easy solution for this.

Liquid has the [`forloop` object](https://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-documentation/objects/for-loops), which can be used inside a loop to access some of its properties.
One of those properties is [`forloop.last`](https://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-documentation/objects/for-loops#last):

> Returns `true` if it's the last iteration of the for loop. Returns `false` if it is not the last iteration.

In other words, you can just do this:

```
{% if forloop.last == false %}
  <hr>
{% endif %}
```